# Ranger-trino connect: trino failed to find service class org.apache.ranger.services.trino.RangerServiceTrino

Tags: java, trino, apache-ranger

I am trying to create a trino service in apache ranger in local using docker. I tried below steps:

1. Build the ranger code
2. `./ranger_in_docker up`
   The ranger UI is coming up and ranger server starts without any issue, and I am able to login to it.

Similarly I build the trino in local and started the server , which also starts on default port : 8080 in local.

Now when i try to create trino service in ranger , its giving me this error:

> trino failed to find service class
> org.apache.ranger.services.trino.RangerServiceTrino. Resource lookup
> will not be available. Please make sure plugin jar is in the correct
> place

I tried checking the ranger and trino logs , but there is no entry in both about this request.

Also i tried putting the trino ranger-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-trino-plugin jar to trino's plugin folder and restarted the whole ranger and trino but it still gives the same error.

Can someone please help me about this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Trino plugin in Ranger is available only for JDK 11. So, you must build Ranger project passing the profile `ranger-jdk11` to `mvn` params.
You can try this:

```
mvn clean compile package \
-P ranger-jdk11,-linux \
eclipse:eclipse
```

You must have JDK 11 installed and configured on your machine to this works, inclusive the `JAVA_HOME` pointing to `jdk11`.
This will create the necessary `jars` into `ranger-2.3.0-admin/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/ranger-plugins/trino`, then the Ranger Admin will not through this error message.

```
ll /usr/lib/ranger/ranger-2.3.0-admin/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/ranger-plugins/trino
total 7424
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Jun 13 09:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 ranger ranger    4096 Jun 13 09:20 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     53162 Jun 13 09:20 ranger-trino-plugin-2.3.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   6735843 Jun 13 09:20 trino-jdbc-377.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    801586 Jun 13 09:20 trino-spi-377.jar
```